# How to format the text of the choices in a ReferenceInput field in react-admin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

The ReferenceInput field in combination with SelectInput allows to populate the option texts from a column of a referenced resource by giving the name of the column like so:

```
<ReferenceInput label="Location name" source="id" reference="Location">
 <SelectInput optionText={"building"} />
</ReferenceInput>
```

I'd like to combine the option text from several columns, but I don't know how I access the current record. 
I want to achieve something like in this code (that of course does not work, just to show what I mean):

```
<ReferenceInput label="Location name" source="id" reference="Location">
 <SelectInput optionText=`${record.building} ${record.room}` />
</ReferenceInput>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`optionText` also accepts a function, so you can shape the option text at will:

```
const choices = [
   { id: 123, first_name: 'Leo', last_name: 'Tolstoi' },
   { id: 456, first_name: 'Jane', last_name: 'Austen' },
];
const optionRenderer = choice => `${choice.first_name} ${choice.last_name}`;
<SelectInput source="author_id" choices={choices} optionText={optionRenderer} />
```

`optionText` also accepts a React Element, that will be cloned and receive
the related choice as the `record` prop. You can use Field components there.

```
const choices = [
   { id: 123, first_name: 'Leo', last_name: 'Tolstoi' },
   { id: 456, first_name: 'Jane', last_name: 'Austen' },
];
const FullNameField = ({ record }) => <span>{record.first_name} {record.last_name}</span>;
<SelectInput source="gender" choices={choices} optionText={<FullNameField />}/>
```

Comment: great, thanks! So it's actually called record, I wasn't far :)

Comment: Does not work. Tried with choice and record. Both undefined. I checked the props. Empty.